# Request the return type of any c function

Tags: c, unix

Is there an easy way to request by a unix command or c instruction the return type of any c library function if the man page does not exist?

Comment: Look in the header file?

Comment: Probably need to `grep` the name of the function somewhere like `/usr/include`.

Comment: If it's a POSIX function or command, you can also consult the specification itself.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. What vare you _actually_ trying to achieve?